# What does PECI stand for in PECI CPU temperature?

Tags: hardware

I used `istats scan` to get a list of all my temperature readings.

What are TCGC PECI GPU, TCSA PECI SA, and TCXC PECI CPU? I think the TCXC etc. are just codes that refer to these sensors, but what does the PECI stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### PECI = Platform Environmental Control Interface

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Environment_Control_Interface):

> Platform Environment Control Interface, abbreviated as PECI, is an Intel proprietary single wire serial interface that provides a communication channel between Intel processors and chipset components to external system management logic and thermal monitoring devices.